# How to generate range with MIN MAX using Array.from

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, range

Using  `Array.from` , I can create range from `0` to `N-1` as following :

```js
var N=6;
log( Array.from({length:N},(v,k)=>k) )
```

```html
<script>var log=(m)=>console.log(m)</script>
```

This generate `[0,1,2,...,N-1]`

My question is how to generate a range with `Min` & `Max` bounds in general using **Array.from** not something elese (Not restrict to `0` as 1st element of range ) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible By  identifying  the length of range :  `MAX-MIN+1` AND identifying the first element of this range  : `k+MIN` .

Then :

```js
var MIN=18,MAX=23 //--> [18,19,20,21,22,23] EXPECTED
console.log(
    Array.from({length:MAX-MIN+1},(v,k)=>k+MIN)
  )
```

Comment: Just wanted to add here, if OP doesn't want the range to include the Max value, then just set {length: MAX - MIN} without the +1.

Comment: @Kadima. this is Good hint  . thanks.. The question is good because it will facilate migration to ES6 & avoid external libraries for this issue (generate Range)